# Angular 8 migration to Angular 16 <Div> HTMLDivElements are now different

Tags: angular, angular16

Here is a stackblitz of an Angular 8 drag drop example that works fine.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-dragdrop
Migrating same example to Angular 16, it no longer works as the returned divs are completely different, which results in the DOMcontainer.indexOf(eli) returning -1. See debugger images.

Image of debugging the v8 version, all divs are uniform as HTMLDivElements

[image: Angular 8 version returning HTMLDivElements]

In v16, pictured below, these are the different div elements that are returned by

```
let DOMdragEl = e.source.element.nativeElement; // dragged element
let DOMcontainer = Array.from(DOMdragEl.parentElement!.children); //list of divs
```

This causes
`let CurrDOMelIndexi = DOMcontainer.indexOf(eli);`
to fail with a -1, not found. (shown in image)

This image shows the results in the debugger.
[image: v16 returns different set of divs]

My question is why are the divs different?
More importantly, why do the divs no longer match in the returned array?
They should still be found correct?
and how to deal with it properly? Make this work in v16?

Thank you

TRIED:
I ran through the debugger to view the returned differences, and do not understand the returned results, and why the divs in v16 are not in the container.

Comment: Don't know if this helps you, but it looks like DOMcontainer holds children of the <BODY> tag.